# Server performance in nodejs script running forever

Tags: node.js

I have following code running with forever in nodejs.

https://gist.github.com/yalamber/8035e853f0508edb060e

What it basically does is look for files in specific directory with inotify module and sends new files content to a specific url as post.

What I am thinking about is memory or performance issues as i run this server with forever module. It is running always in the server. Will it cause any problem to server performance?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into using either [setInterval](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_arg) or [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) to explicitly run this as often as you need to, instead of relying solely on forever.

Comment: I think inotify will help in that part. it notifies whenever there is new file.